# How to operate a BLDC motor?

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino Uno to operate a BLDC motor using IR2110 MOSFET driver and IRFZ44N MOSFET. But every time, all the low side MOSFETs and phase 3 driver(IR2110) are burning. In this position my motor is only vibrating but not moving.[image] How do I solve this?

```
void AH_BL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x04;
  PORTD &= ~0x18;
  PORTD |=  0x20;
  TCCR1A =  0;            // Turn pin 11 (OC2A) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 10 OFF)
  TCCR2A =  0x81;         //
}
void AH_CL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x02;
  PORTD &= ~0x18;
  PORTD |=  0x20;
  TCCR1A =  0;            // Turn pin 11 (OC2A) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 10 OFF)
  TCCR2A =  0x81;         //
}
void BH_CL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x02;
  PORTD &= ~0x28;
  PORTD |=  0x10;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 10 (OC1B) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x21;         //
}
void BH_AL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x08;
  PORTD &= ~0x28;
  PORTD |=  0x10;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 10 (OC1B) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x21;         //
}
void CH_AL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x08;
  PORTD &= ~0x30;
  PORTD |=  0x08;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 9 (OC1A) PWM ON (pin 10 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x81;         //
}
void CH_BL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x04;
  PORTD &= ~0x30;
  PORTD |=  0x08;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 9 (OC1A) PWM ON (pin 10 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x81;         //
}
```

Comment: Please add oscillograms of all your control signals.

Comment: sorry,I cannot provide all the MOSFET wave form due to lack of oscilloscope

Comment: It will be VERY difficult to diagnose the problem without the waveforms, as you don't know if you are driving the FETs correctly at all. You may shoot them through and not even know it.

Comment: then you can maybe add the source code of how you drive your mosfets

Comment: void AH_BL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x04;
  PORTD &= ~0x18;
  PORTD |=  0x20;
  TCCR1A =  0;            // Turn pin 11 (OC2A) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 10 OFF)
  TCCR2A =  0x81;         //
}
void AH_CL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x02;
  PORTD &= ~0x18;
  PORTD |=  0x20;
  TCCR1A =  0;            // Turn pin 11 (OC2A) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 10 OFF)
  TCCR2A =  0x81;         //
}

Comment: void BH_CL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x02;
  PORTD &= ~0x28;
  PORTD |=  0x10;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 10 (OC1B) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x21;         //
}
void BH_AL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x08;
  PORTD &= ~0x28;
  PORTD |=  0x10;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 10 (OC1B) PWM ON (pin 9 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x21;         //
}

Comment: void CH_AL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x08;
  PORTD &= ~0x30;
  PORTD |=  0x08;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 9 (OC1A) PWM ON (pin 10 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x81;         //
}
void CH_BL()
{
  PORTB  =  0x04;
  PORTD &= ~0x30;
  PORTD |=  0x08;
  TCCR2A =  0;            // Turn pin 9 (OC1A) PWM ON (pin 10 & pin 11 OFF)
  TCCR1A =  0x81;         //
}

Comment: use the edit function and then include your codes into your question

Comment: There is no need to add a parallel resistor on the gate, specially not 1k it has too small resistance. The gate driver has a push-pull output, when no voltage is present the low side is conducting. But the probable cause of burning MOSFETs is the cross conduction

Comment: At first i have done experiment without resistor,at that time MOSFET was very hot.After that from google i got the information to add an extra 1K resistor.So that the resistor is there.

Comment: this code used for IR2104 driver NOT for IR2110.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common causes for burning lowside mosfets are: missing deadtime in PWM mode or errors in commutation tables.

What I would advice:

- Make a simple commutation table in a switch case without PWM. Just to check that the motor will turn and your electronics are correct (voltage and current should be limited by using an lab power supply). Or don't connect the motor and measure the gate voltages with a multi-meter step by step.
- Be sure to do the math on the components. Focus on MOSFET turn on/off times, rate of gate charge, max driver current, and max drain source voltage. This allows to calculated a correct bootstrap capacitor value (are you using 22uF? this is **way** to high).
- Start digging in the microcontrollers datasheet to find a way to enable complement PWM with deadtime, if this is not available most of the current will freewheel through the MOSFET's diodes which can be the cause of extreme overheating. So a quick but very dirty fix is adding parallel (with lover Vf) diodes to the MOSFETs.

Comment: Yes,all MOSFET are conducting under switch case condition. 22uF capacitor due to high frequency PWM signal(31KHz).That is the body diode of the MOSFET.

Comment: Without motor electronic part working perfectly.

Comment: Try stepping through the cases without PWM (on/off) and the motor connected. It should turn in this case. But mind the fact that the bootstrap capacitor should be charged before the high gate can be turned on. Removing the 1K resistor could also prevent draining the capacitor to quick.

Comment: Actually i don't understand what u are telling,switch means physical switch or switch case(code) ,What you  are talking about.

Comment: I meant stepping through the switch cases (motor commutation steps). This way it is possible to verify the commutation table and the MOSFET drivers. Initialize the circuit by turning all the low MOSFETs ON for a few milli seconds to charge the bootstrap capacitors. When this works step for step you can try hooking up a motor to verify that it is rotating.